# Mouse movement in KVM is much slower than VirtualBox, any work arounds?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kvm

I'm running KVM in latest Ubuntu, mouse seems pretty slow compared to host machine, the cursor looks "heavy" to me,

Anyone know what could possibly wrong ? I use a wireless mouse that connects through a USB port.

Comment: I had the same problem on a touchpad while running Ubuntu VirtualBox with Win7 being the main OS on my laptop. Will let you know if I figure anything out when I use it next.